# spinner in a FragmentTabHost crashes my app android-eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, spinner

I'm new developing apps for android and I have found some problems adding spinners.

My app have a main menu where after to click on a button a new activity appears which is a FragmentTabHost and it has two tabs.

each tab has its xlm file and its java file, the java file looks as follow

```
package com.bjv01;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

  public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        }
     }
```

But, when i try to add the spinner the app crashes, i just add this code:

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      Spinner sp = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                 ArrayAdapter adapter =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.tipos,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 sp.setAdapter(adapter);


           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);


  }
```

The app compiles perfectly, In fact I can launch the app however when I click on the button that open the activity with the two taps appears the message Unfortunately the app Name has stopped.

Somebody can help me? i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

EDIT:

OK, When I compile the app I don't get any error on the ErroLog, however when the app crashes i get this error on the LogCAT (Click on the link to see the image, sorry I can't upload images yet)

http://i62.tinypic.com/23tnr5u.png

Comment: Can you captures the logs of your crash and paste it here? It should explains you exactly where is your error.

Comment: Could you add tab1.xml and tab2.xml ?

Comment: @VincentD. I can't add images directly. I don't get any error on the ErroLog, however when the app crashes i get this error on the LogCAT, here is a capture: http://i62.tinypic.com/23tnr5u.png

Comment: Check your logs, you have a null value on line 24 of your tab1.java